# Socket.io in ionic cordova

Tags: angularjs, socket.io, ionic-framework

Initially I have used btford socket.io library for my ionic project, but I am having trouble working with it. Now I am trying to install socket.io directly to an ionic project. However I am not sure whether it should installed as an npm install which will store it in the node_modules folder, or should i store the library in ionicprj/www/lib ?

Comment: What kind of trouble did you have with btford's library ?

Comment: I was gonna recomend @btford project angular-socket-io but looks like you tried it. I have not yet gave it a shot but in the next 3 days i will be implementing Sockets into my app for a live chat system and i will post here when i do that with my answer and solution on how i did it.

Answer (score 1):

[cordova-plugin-whitelist](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-whitelist) seems to be "mandatory" at present.

**install it**

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-whitelist
```

**configure config.xml**

You can keep your current setup with * or change for more restrictive rules

**add a html** policy on index.html, you shall add a Policy also. To authorise everything, here it is :

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; 
style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe eval'">
```

Answer (score 0):

socket.io client library should go in `www/lib/` to emit events from the ionic app. On the server you'll want socket.io as an npm module.

There's a helpful tutorial here: http://www.htmlxprs.com/post/6/creating-a-realtime-image-sharing-app-with-ionic-and-socketio-tutorial